# Format time to mm:ss.S with String.format in Kotlin/Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, formatting, duration

I want my time to be formated like: 03:04.9 (example)

This is what I have right now:

```
fun formatTime(data: Long): String {
    val seconds = ((data / 1000.0) % 60.0)
    val minutes = (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(data) % 60).toInt()
    return String.format(Locale.US, "%02d:%.1f", minutes, seconds)
}
```

It kind of works but doesn't make sure that the seconds value has two digits.
This is how the output looks like when the seconds are under 10:
03:4.9

I think I'm so close but just can't get it right

Comment: First, use `java.time.Duration` or a Kotlin equivalent for a duration. Not a `Long`. Next search for how to format a duration in Java. It's been covered more than once already.

Comment: If `dur` is your `Duration` I’d probably use `String.format(Locale.US, "%02d:%02d.%1d", dur.toMinutes(), dur.toSecondsPart(), dur.toMillisPart() / 100)`. Gives `03:04.9`. If you can’t avoid getting a `Long`, you will need `dur = Duration.ofMillis(data);` first.

Comment: Not that you want it here, but formatting a decimal number with leading zeroes is not that hard when you know how. `String.format(Locale.US, "%02d:%04.1f", minutes, seconds)` The `%04.1f` means zero-padded, total width of 4 including the decimal part and 1 decimal after the point, so it gives you what you asked for: `03:04.9`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, its not possible to have control on leading zeros using string formatting.
Alternately you can use [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) to achieve this.

```
fun formatTime(data: Long): String {
    val seconds = ((data / 1000.0) % 60.0)
    val minutes = (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(data) % 60).toInt()
    val formatSeconds = DecimalFormat("00.0").format(seconds)
    return String.format(Locale.US, "%02d:$formatSeconds", minutes)
}
```

This will provide outputs like,

```
03:14.9
03:04.9
03:00.9
03:00.0
03:04.0
```

#### Update:


Thanks [Ole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v) pointing it out in comment(Credits to him).
It is possible to with String.format() function itself, like below.

```
String.format(Locale.US, "%02d:%04.1f", minutes, seconds)
```

Also as Ole mentioned that, it is always better to use `kotlin.time.Duration` or `java.time.Duration` classes when you handle time.